# Issue with date variables in vb .Net

Tags: vb.net, date

I have this code:

```
 Private Function mayIComeIn() As Boolean
    With System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
        Dim dStartDate As Date = .Item("StartDate")
        Dim dEndDate As Date = .Item("EndDate")
        If dStartDate <= Date.Now.Date And Date.Now.Date <= dEndDate Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End With
End Function
```

These are the values in the web.config (I am using **day/month/year** as date format):

> add key="StartDate" value="14/11/2104"
>      add key="EndDate" value="31/12/2015"

With those values `dStartDate <= Date.Now.Date` returns false.

Likewise `date.Compare(dStartDate, Date.now.Date)` returns 1

As far as I can tell StartDate is earlier than Date.Now, so I was expecting the return values to be True for the compare operator or -1 for the date.compare() 
function.

I am missing something, or how I should compare the two dates to know wich one is earlier?

Comment: Those dates look like strings, so convert it to a date with Date.TryParse.

Comment: 2104 is also larger than today. Should that be 2014?

Comment: oh boy that's it, I'm becoming dyslexic or something